# CSS HTML Strange White Space

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website and there's a strange white space at the bottom of the page (only at IE). safari is fine. i am using ie8.

I want the white background ended after that black navigation links.

http://www.applezone.com.hk/newrx/

I can't figure out which part of the css causing that white space.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not seeing any of this "strange white space"...

Comment: I want the white background end just below that black navigation links.

Comment: It's there. Look at it in another browser too, it's pretty obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (Firefox add-on) you can select that white space and it will show you where it is in the DOM, i.e. what the HTML is that is actually generating it - which element it's part of.

You can also switch on and off the individual styles on the fly.

The equivalent in IE is to hit F12 and get the 'Developer Tools' console. Find -> Select Element by Click.

Comment: I used the  'Developer Tools' console and found out it was because of the height of iframe, thank you so much !! problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

try adding those:

```
.navlink{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 51px;
}
```

i don't have IE8 to test on but i do use "IE tester" program which showed me the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `display:block` and/or `margin:0` and/or `padding:0` for the element in question. One of them is going to be the culprit.